VS Code terminal - log everything into txt file?
I log to file everything from my Bash console. I do it with the following code added to my .bashrc:
start_terminal_logging()
{
    if [ -z "$SCRIPT_LOG_FILE_ACTIVE" ]; then
        # Log each session to a separate file:
        logdir=~/.terminal_logs
        logfile=$logdir/session_log_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)_$$.txt
        # If no folder exist make one:
        if [ ! -d $logdir ]; then
            mkdir -p $logdir
        fi
        export SCRIPT_LOG_FILE_ACTIVE=$logfile
        # Start logging, a=append, q=quiet:
        script -aq $logfile
        exit
    fi
}

# Start the logging(script above):
start_terminal_logging

This creates a file session_log_$datetime.txt for each terminal session, and saves everything into it.
However, when I launch the terminal from within VS Code, it doesn't work, there is no txt file created at all. How can I log VS Code terminal outputs into file too?

In what way doesn't it work? Does vscode even run your bashrc?

it doesn't work is perhaps the worst problem description one can think of.... Voting to close,

I'd expect it to run .bashrc as the shell is started, no?

Seems like $SCRIPT_LOG_FILE_ACTIVE is inherited from the environment and isn't empty in cases when VS Code launches terminal sessions (not sure why).
I fixed the issue by going to VS Code's "Configure Terminal Settings" and under Terminal>Integrated>Env:Linux it says: "Object with environment variables that will be added to the VS Code process to be used by the terminal on Linux. Set to null to delete the environment variable."
So I added the following to settings.json:
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
        "SCRIPT_LOG_FILE_ACTIVE": null,
    }

This resets the $SCRIPT_LOG_FILE_ACTIVE variable, and now the logging in VS Code works.
